# Remotely controlling a computer with no connected screens

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, nfs, home-server, windows-server

I have an old computer which I intend to use as a NFS and torrent server, running regular windows 10. Right now it's connected to a screen, but I'd like to use that screen elsewhere, and anyway a server doesn't really need a screen.

However, I don't want to plug in a monitor every time I need to preform maintenance or change something. So the best option is to remote control it from another computer (either using Windows remote control or Chrome Remote desktop, etc.).

Is this possible? Maybe I should install windows server fo better suite my needs? Any advice will be great.

Comment: It is possible. Remote control does not require monitor. I have used teamviewer before, but another other software with similar function should  work as well.

Comment: Use RDP (Remote Desktop) or possibly VNC - but seriously, why not just run Linux - NFS is a Unix protocol.

Comment: Thanks, lyang, I'll try.
@davidgo - will it work? All of my computers run windows, which means they use SAMBA, so I'm pretty sure I won't be able to see the Linux machine over the network.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. SAMBA is the Unix software for WINDOWS filesharing. Its good, but it plays catchup with Windows. NFS is Unix filesharing - there are windows clients for it - your post talks about an NFS server on Windowsv10. (did you mean windows file sharing?)

Comment: @davidgo Then I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge - two years ago I was messing around with file sharing between windows and Ubuntu, so I remembered SAMBA to be a windows network file sharing protocol for some reason. That's what I meant, though (Windows file sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Just take the former pc on remote and you will see the GUI in the rdp window. No need of a screen attached to the former pc.

Comment: My pleasure to help.